# ¿Como crear un button con jquery y que contenga una etiqueta span?

Tags: jquery

Creo la el `button` con `jQuery` me funciona pero no logro hacer que las etiquetas `span` me las reconozca con `html`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Crear', function() {
        var boton = $('<button/>', {
            'type'  : 'button',
            'class' : 'editar edit-modal btn btn-warning',
            'id'    : 'ButtonEditar',
            'text'    : '<span class="fa fa-edit"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Editar</span>'
        });
        $( '#contenedor').append(boton.prop('outerHTML'));
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
<button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar</span>
</button>

<div id="contenedor">
</div>
```

Comment: Con javascript podrías colocal ago como: `document.getElementById('tuBoton').InnerHTML = "tu código HTML"; ` ¿has intentado un ajuste similar al que sugiero o necesitas una solución netamente en Jquery?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave shhh en eso se basa mi respuesta xDD

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solo tienes un pequeño error en vez de usar `text` usa `html`.

`text` solo es para texto y `html` se renderiza como elemento del `DOM`

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Crear', function() {
        var boton = $('<button/>', {
            'type'  : 'button',
            'class' : 'editar edit-modal btn btn-warning',
            'id'    : 'ButtonEditar',
            'html'    : '<span class="fa fa-edit"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Editar</span>'
        });
        $( '#contenedor').append(boton.prop('outerHTML'));
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
<button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar</span>
</button>

<div id="contenedor">
</div>
```

---

Tomando en cuenta la propuesta de [@User2930137](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/60392/6635) solo una pequeña modificación pero es exactamente lo mismo, tal vez si un poco mas compleja

La modificación consta en solo hacer un solo `.append()` de la siguiente forma:

```
.append(
  $('<span />', {
    'class': 'fa fa-edit'
  })
  ,
  $('<span />', {
    'class': 'hidden-xs',
    'text': 'Editar'
  })
);
```

Lo que se esta haciendo realmente aquí es crear dos elementos y al concatenar con `.append()` son separados por `,`.
Así se evita hacer 2 `.append()` de dos elementos `$('#contenedor').append(boton.append(span).append(span2));` como lo hace [@User2930137](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/60392/6635).

Resultado final

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Crear', function() {
  var boton = $('<button/>', {
    'type': 'button',
    'class': 'editar edit-modal btn btn-warning',
    'id': 'ButtonEditar'
  }).append(
    $('<span />', {
      'class': 'fa fa-edit'
    }),
    $('<span />', {
      'class': 'hidden-xs',
      'text': 'Editar'
    })
  );

  $('#contenedor').append(boton);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar</span>
</button>

<div id="contenedor">
</div>
```

Comment: justo lo que buscaba

Comment: Una pregunta mas: ¿Como puedo indicar la etiqueta `disabled`? intento con `'disabled' : true` y no me funciona.

Comment: @PabloContreras si me funciona poniendo eso. recordaste añadir la coma separando atributos?

Comment: era eso @lois6b gracias.

Answer (score 8):

En vez de poner el `span` en el attributo `texto`, tras crear el boton, y cogiendo su `ID` se lo metes en el `innerHTML`

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Crear', function() {

  if (!document.getElementById("ButtonEditar")) {
    var boton = $('<button/>', {
      'type': 'button',
      'class': 'editar edit-modal btn btn-warning',
      'id': 'ButtonEditar'

    });

    $('#contenedor').append(boton);
    document.getElementById("ButtonEditar").innerHTML = '<span class="fa fa-edit"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Editar</span>';
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar</span>
</button>

<div id="contenedor">
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, @lois6b, tu ejemplo no funciona en mi navegador. Sigo dando clics en el bottón del plus después del primer elemento creado los demás me los crea sin el icono de editar.

Comment: @user2930137 oh :/ qué navegador usas?

Comment: Chrome. A ti sí te salen todos los botones creados a partr del plus con el signo de editar?

Comment: mano, a mi tambien me pasa igual que a @user2930137, y utilizo `chrome` la ultima version.

Comment: lois6b, ¿estás seguro/a de que si creas muchos botones dándole varios clics a tu icono de plus te los crea correctamente? Está raro xd

Comment: aaaaah @user2930137 teneis razon. y es porque al darle multiples clicks siempre se crea con el mismo ID  y no debe repetirse el id (identificador unico) . o se cambia o se comprueba que no exista ese boton ya

Comment: cheka: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjKZH.png`

Comment: Así es, trata de modificarlo y arreglarlo; si no hay manera no quedará de otra que quitar la respuesta para evitar confusiones y errores de programadores que puedan utilizar tu respuesta como solución. Saludos!

Comment: @user2930137 editado para que no salgan multiples botones (comprobando si existe o no )

Answer (score 7):

La manera en que intentabas hacer esto con jQuery sería la creación de tres objetos; uno el botón y los otros los span y hacerlo justo como lo intentabas.

Tomé prestado el código de @JuankGlezz y modifiqué lo necesario para este ejemplo.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Crear', function() {
        var boton = $('<button/>', {
            'type'  : 'button',
            'class' : 'editar edit-modal btn btn-warning',
            'id'    : 'ButtonEditar'
        });
        var span = $('<span />', {
            'class' : 'fa fa-edit'
        }); 
        var span2 = $('<span />', {
            'class' : 'hidden-xs',
            'text' : 'Editar'
        });
 
        $('#contenedor').append(boton.append(span).append(span2));
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
<button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar</span>
</button>

<div id="contenedor">
</div>
```

Comment: Me gusta! no es necesario usar `$(boton)`, puede ser directamente `boton.append` ;)

Comment: Vale, ya lo modifico ehehe gracias

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear el botón a partir de una cadena literal

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Crear', function() {
  var boton = '<button class="editar edit-modal btn btn-warning" type="button" id="ButtonEditar"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Editar</span></button>';
  $('#contenedor').append(boton);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    <span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar</span>
</button>

<div id="contenedor">
</div>
```